# ACH payments does not work with Authorize.NET

Tags: php, authorize.net

A user is trying to make an ACH payment from our portal but it doesn't work , I get an Error - the ABA code is invalid (but its a valid code..) , when he does the same payment directly with Authorize.NET portal, it does work.

Can anybody advise? I tired to contact Authorize.NET but had no response.

This is the code:

```
/**
 * Debit a Bank Account
 * Use this method to process an ACH debit transaction using bank account details.
 * @param float $amount
 * @param int $routingNumber
 * @param int $accountNumber
 * @param string $nameOnAccount
 * @param string $bankName
 * @return array
 */
public function paymentTransactionsDebitBankAccount(
    float $amount,
    int $routingNumber,
    int $accountNumber,
    string $nameOnAccount,
    string $bankName,
    string $accountType,
    string $eCheckType
): array
{
    $paymentTransactions = new PaymentTransactions(
        $this->apiLoginId,
        $this->transactionKey,
        $this->apiKey,`your text`
        $this->endPointApi
    );


    $paymentTransactions->setOrderInformation(
        orderInformationInvoiceNumber: $this->contract->id,
        orderInformationDescription: 'Contract ' . $this->contract->name
    );

    $paymentTransactions->setTransactionRequest(
        transactionRequestType: 'authCaptureTransaction'
    );

    $debitBankAccount = $paymentTransactions->debitBankAccount(
        amount: $amount,
        routingNumber: $routingNumber,
        accountNumber: $accountNumber,
        nameOnAccount: $nameOnAccount,
        bankName: $bankName,
        accountType: $accountType,
        eCheckType: $eCheckType,
    );

    if ($debitBankAccount != null) {
        if ($debitBankAccount->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok") {
            $tresponse = $debitBankAccount->getTransactionResponse();

            if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getMessages() != null) {
                $debitBankAccountMessageText = " Transaction Response code : " . $tresponse->getResponseCode() . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Debit Bank Account APPROVED  :" . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Debit Bank Account AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Debit Bank Account TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Code : " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getCode() . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Description : " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getDescription() . "\n";

                return [
                    'status' => 'Ok',
                    'message' => $debitBankAccountMessageText,
                    'data' => [
                        'transaction_response_code' => $tresponse->getResponseCode(),
                        'transaction_id' => $tresponse->getTransId(),
                        'auth_code' => $tresponse->getAuthCode(),
                        'message_code' => $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getCode(),
                        'message_description' => $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getDescription()
                    ],
                ];

            } else {
                $debitBankAccountMessageText = "Transaction Failed \n";
                if ($tresponse->getErrors() != null) {
                    $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Error code  : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                    $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Error message : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";
                }

                return [
                    'status' => 'Error',
                    'message' => $debitBankAccountMessageText,
                    'data' => null,
                ];
            }
        } else {
            $debitBankAccountMessageText = "Transaction Failed \n";
            $tresponse = $debitBankAccount->getTransactionResponse();
            if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getErrors() != null) {
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Error code  : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Error message : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";
            } else {
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Error code  : " . $debitBankAccount->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getCode() . "\n";
                $debitBankAccountMessageText .= " Error message : " . $debitBankAccount->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getText() . "\n";
            }

            return [
                'status' => 'Error',
                'message' => $debitBankAccountMessageText,
                'data' => null,
            ];
        }
    } else {
        return [
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'No response returned',
            'data' => null,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What value are you passing in for ABA? What is the exact error message you get? Post *your* code that shows how you are using this.

Comment: the value is actually the routing number, the exact error: Transaction Failed Error code: 9 Error message:The ABA code is invalid

Comment: if ($merchantAccount->merchant_account_type_id == 1) {
            $merchantAccountCustomerInfo = [
                'routing_number' => $dataPayment['routing_number'],
                'account_number' => $dataPayment['account_number'],
                'name_on_account' => $dataPayment['name_on_account'],
                'bank_name' => $dataPayment['bank_name'],
                'account_type' => $dataPayment['account_type'],
                'e_check_type' => $dataPayment['e_check_type'],

Comment: Please update your question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main checks for ABA numbers for ACH.  From the Active list of Banks and the Check Digit for the RDFI Identification Number.

For the Active list of banks, you can't pull that information directly from the FED anymore, but you can check banks singly through their web site:  https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/search.html

For the Check Digit ( RDFI Ident is the first 8 digits of the Routing Number/ABA Number ), the formula is:
(3(d1 + d4 + d7) + 7(d2 + d5 + d8) + (d3 + d6 + d9)) mod 10 = 0

Here's a good test ABA number:  123456780.
The Math:

```
3's Places Values = 1, 4, 7 = (1+4+7)*3 = 36 
7's Places Values = 2, 5, 8 = (2+5+8)*7 = 105 
1's Places Values = 3, 6, 0 = (3+6+0)*1 = 9 

36 + 105 + 9 = 150
150 mod 10 = 0, so this is valid.
```

Let's do an invalid one:  111222444

```
3's Places Values = 1, 2, 4 = (1+2+4)*3 = 21 
7's Places Values = 1, 2, 4 = (1+2+4)*7 = 47 
1's Places Values = 1, 2, 4 = (1+2+4)*1 = 7 

21 + 47 + 7 = 77
77 mod 10 = 7, not zero.  This is invalid.
```

You can get more information on that here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_routing_transit_number

There are also a set of banks that are typically not allowed by most ACH Processors.  These include the FED banks that are government internal instead of consumer or business facing.